# convert array of uint64_t to __m256i

Tags: c, avx, avx2

I have four `uint64_t` numbers and I wish to combine them as parts of a `__m256i`, however, I'm lost as to how to go about this.

Here's one attempt (where `rax`, `rbx`, `rcx`, and `rdx` are `uint64_t`):

```
uint64_t a [4] = {rax,rbx,rcx,rcx};

__m256i t = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i *) &a);
```

Comment: The type name is `uint` not `unit` :)

Comment: What's wrong with what you tried?

Comment: See also, `_mm256_set_epi64x`

Comment: @cat phone spell check

Comment: @NationWidePants ah. If you posted involved questions about CPU arithmetic intrinsics from within the vicinity of a compiler then you might be able to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) :P

Comment: @cat but it was, and is, and someone with some knowledge of c answered.

Comment: Use std vector types and tell the compiler to optimize with intrinsics. (often /Oi switch)

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan That's for VS, what about GCC / Clang?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html
-o3 would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *already* have an array, then yes absolutely use `_mm256_loadu_si256` (or even the aligned version, `_mm256_load_si256` if your array is `alignas(32)`.)  But generally don't create an array just to store into / reload from.

---

Use the `_mm_set` intrinsics and let the compiler decide how to do it.  Note that they take their args with the highest-numbered element first:  e.g.

```
__m256i vt = _mm256_set_epi64x(rdx, rcx, rbx, rax);
```

You typically don't want the asm to look anything like your scalar store -> vector load C source, because that would produce a store-forwarding stall.

gcc 6.1 "sees through" the local array in this case (and uses 2x `vmovq` / 2x `vpinsrq` / 1x `vinserti128`), but it still generates code to align the stack to 32B.  (Even though it's not needed because it didn't end up needing any 32B-aligned locals).

As you can see on the [Godbolt Compiler Explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g6,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B11+-Wall+-Wextra+-O3+-fverbose-asm+-march%3Dhaswell+-ffast-math%27,source:%27%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%0A__m256i+combine4(uint64_t+rax,+uint64_t+rbx,+uint64_t+rcx,+uint64_t+rdx)+%7B%0A++return+_mm256_set_epi64x(rdx,+rcx,+rbx,+rax)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A__m256i+combine4_array(uint64_t+rax,+uint64_t+rbx,+uint64_t+rcx,+uint64_t+rdx)+%7B%0A++uint64_t+a+%5B4%5D+%3D+%7Brax,rbx,rcx,rdx%7D%3B%0A%0A++__m256i+t+%3D+_mm256_load_si256((__m256i+*)+%26a)%3B%0A%0A++return+t%3B%0A%7D%0A%27)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3), the actual data-movement part of both ways is the same, but the array way has a bunch of wasted instructions that gcc failed to optimize away after deciding to avoid the bad way that the source was implying.

`_mm256_set_epi64x` works in 32bit code (with gcc at least).  You get 2x `vmovq` and 2x `vmovhps` to do 64bit loads to the upper half of an xmm register.  (Add `-m32` to the compile options in the godbolt link).

Comment: Does anyone even use `_set_`? It seems that `_setr_` is more intuitive. This whole illusion of big-endian at the intrinsic level does nothing but confuse the crap out of all the low-level x86 programmers who eat little-endian for breakfast.

Comment: @Mysticial: Highest element first makes vector left-shifts actually go left, and makes your vectors match the way the insn ref manual describes them and shows them in diagrams.  I find this useful when figuring out whether I can replace a shuffle with an `_mm_srli_epi64` or something.  Yes it's confusing, but `_setr_` isn't the only place it occurs.  I'm glad they provided both intrinsics, so you can choose the one that matches the ordering you use in comments / variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure your CPU even supports these AVX instructions: [Performing AVX integer operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284263/performing-avx-integer-operation).

Secondly, from https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/514151, the pointer argument must be an aligned location. Conventionally allocated memory addresses on the stack are random and depend on the sizes of stack frames from previous calls, so may not be aligned.

Instead, just use the intrinsic type `__m256i` to *force* the compiler to align it; *OR*, according to https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/582952, use `__declspec(align)` on your `a` array.

Comment: I wrote a cpuid check before it, so I know what's supported, just data type issues. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: You shouldn't use a scratch array at all; `_mm256_set_epi64x` produces better code.

Comment: @PeterCordes to clarify why I used a "scratch array": this was written for cython. I didn't have much of a choice if I wanted a good means by which to interface with the python side.